# A problem in group theory and representation theory.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, derived-subgroup

Suppose that $H = \{1, h, h^2, \ldots, h^{n-1}\}$ is a normal subgroup of a finite non-abelian group $G$
having  order $n$. It is known that $H$ is cyclic with generator $h$. Let $c_G$ be the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. Let $$c_G=nc_{G/H},$$ where $G/H/ is the quotient group.

Let $G'$ be the derived (or commutator) subgroup of $G$. For each $1\leq i \leq n-1$,  it is known that  $$h^i\notin G'.$$
This condition implies that G has a set of $n-1$ (distinct) linear representations $\lambda_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n- 1$ with $$\lambda_i(h^i)\neq 1.$$
Is the following statement true?

There exists a primitive $n$th root (let's say $\beta$) of unity such that $$\lambda_i(h^ig)=\beta \lambda_i(g) \ \text{for every}\ g\in G.$$
In other words, we have $$\lambda_1(h^ig)=\beta \lambda_1(g), \ \lambda_2(h^2g)=\beta \lambda_2(g), \ \text{and so on}.$$
I know that if $n$ is replaced with a prime number, then above statement is true. Please help.

Comment: Check for typo: $h_i$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the same and it is edited.

Comment: This is  a very confusing question, and I wonder whether you have stated it as you intended. You have not said that the $\lambda_i$ are distinct. Are you assuming that? Note also that $G'$ is irrelevant - you can assume that $G' = 1 $ and $G$ is abelian. By putting $g=1$, you get $\lambda_i(h^i) = \beta$ for all $i$, and there is not reason why that should be true, even when $n$ is prime.

Comment: @DerekHolt I have made some changes to the post. Kindly relook at it.

Comment: You are still saying that it is true for $n$ prime, but it isn't. Let $G = H$ be cyclic of order $5$, let $\omega$ be a primitive $5$th root of $1$, and choose $\lambda_i$ with $\lambda_1(h) = \omega$, $\lambda_2(h) = \omega^3$, $\lambda_3(h) = \omega^4$ and $\lambda_4(h) = \omega^2$. Then there is no such $\beta$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you please provide an example for non-abelian groups?

Comment: $C_5 \times S_3$ with $H = C_5$. As I said my earlier comment, your assumption that $H \cap G' = 1$ means that the problem reduces to the case when $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the following statement:

Any character of degree $1$ (so $1$-dimensional representation) $\chi$ of a proper subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$ can be extended to a character of $G$ if and only if $\chi(g)=1$ for any $g\in H\cap G’$.

I can give you a proof of this statement if you are interested in, let me know.

However, in your case $H\cap G’=\{1\}$ so the condition of the statement is always satisfied.

How many distinct $1$-dimensional representations has $H$? The number is exactly $|H^*|=|H|=n$. In particular, for any $h^i\neq 1$ there is at least one representation $\lambda_i$ of $H$ (and so also its extension  on $G$) such that $\lambda_i(h^i)\neq 1$. So you have at least $n-1$ distinct representations of $G$ such that $\lambda_i(h^i)\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate how your statement implies the existence of a primitive nth root of unity such that the given conditions hold.

Comment: @MittalG does your primitive root $\beta$ depend from the choice of $i$?

Comment: No. It may be independent

Comment: Also I have added an extra condition in the question related to conjugacy classes that I skipped earlier.